# Set warnings with multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How would I make a multidimensional array by doing the following? (What am i doing wrong?)

```js
var array = [];

array["WARNING"][0] = "WARNING1";
array["WARNING"][1] = "WARNING1";

// This should show both the warnings
console.log(array["WARNING"]);
```

Error shown:

> {   "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of
>   undefined",   "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",   "lineno":
>   15,   "colno": 21 }

Comment: because it is a property with an array, not what you defined. You should really be using an object for the first part, not an array.

Comment: I'd make your initial array an object to make your code more verbose: `logs = {warnings:[], errors:[], info:[]}` Then you can access it with dot notations, `logs.warnings[0];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider to use an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) and assign an array to the wanted property before storing some values.

Even if it works with an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) (this is a special object), I do not recommend to use properties with an array, if only properties are necessary without using indices.

```js
var object = {};

object["WARNING"] =  [];
object["WARNING"][0] = "WARNING1";
object["WARNING"][1] = "WARNING1";

// This should show both the warnings
console.log(object["WARNING"]);
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me this :) - I've got a better understanding now